# Is it possible to retrieve a variable in a derived class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game, and items in this game are scriptable objects. I have the `itemData` script, which holds the info that all items have, like their size and what icon they have in the editor, and then i have the derived classes which are more specific items, like weapons that have damage and consumables that restore a value to a stat.

My Issue is that I cant figure out how to retrieve the value the consumable item restores. I can see in the editor that the `itemData` variable has the scriptable object and then parenthesis next to it that say "Consumable Item".

[image: editorView]

I would think that if the editor can tell that its a derived class then there must be a way to retrieve info on it but i don't know how.

This is the [item data class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmhug.png). It doesn't hold much, only what pretty much every item has.

```
public abstract class itemData : ScriptableObject
{

public EquipmentSlot equipmentType;
public ItemType type;

[TextArea(15,20)]
public string Itemdescription;

public int width = 1;
public int height = 1;

public sprite itemIcon;
public GameObject thisItemObject;

}
```

This is the [consumable item derived class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMzSe.png). For the purposes of today, I'm only trying to retrieve "restoredValue".

```
public class ConsumableItem: itemData{
//eventually ill have to make it so items can restore multiple different values,like a meal item that both hydrates and feeds. Ill probbaly just make RestoredType

public specialEffect specialeffect;//any special effect that this item applies when consumed, like a buff a list and the RestoredValue a list as well
public restoredType restoredType;//the value this item restores when consumed
public int restoredValue;//the amount of points this item restores its target stat, like food or water

public itemData decayItem;//what this item turns into under certain conditions, such as being expired
public itemData useItem;//what this item turns into when it is consumed or used.
}
```

In the script where I'm trying to retrieve the value, I already check for whether or not the item is a consumable type of object, so we don't have to worry about checking and it returning a null value. All I need to know is how to retrieve this int from the derived ConsumableItem class.

```
private void UseItem(Vector2Int tileGridPosition)
{
inventoryItem usedItem = selectedItemGrid.GetItem(tileGridPosition.x, tileGridPosition.y);
if ((usedItem != null)&&(usedItem.itemData.type == ItemType.Consumable)) 
{
//thisCharacterStats.DoStatRestoreValue(consumable item restored type, consumable item restored value);
}
```

and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xqmk.png) is where I'm trying to retrieve it from.
Like i said, it already checks if it is a `consumableitem` type, which only items of the `ConsumableItem` class are, so we shouldn't have to worry about checking for a variable on a different class or anything. And all the `"inventoryItem"` is on the first line of this method is just how i store an `itemData`. Its the only thing it holds that's relevant here.

So how can i retrieve `restoredValue` variable from the `itemData` that I store in the 'used item'? Is it even possible to do here, or am I going to have to change up the way I store items in this project?

Comment: Actual code is always better than screenshots. It allows people to copy it, correct it and then provide an answer. With screenshots they have to retype everything in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the answer to your main question: you should use casting. in short, you can access the variables with the following syntax

```cs
((ConsumableItem)usedItem.itemData).restoredValue
```

However there are three different ways to cast an object to a type, each with their own advantages.

1. using the `as` keyword to safe-cast the object to the type, and if it couldn't instead of throwing exceptions, it'll just make it null

```cs
var consumable = usedItem.itemData as ConsumableItem;
if (consumable is not null) {
   ...
}
```

2. using pattern matching. this way you can do all the two lines in above code in a single line.

```cs
if (usedItem.itemData is ConsumableItem consumable) {
   ...
}
```

(read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/safely-cast-using-pattern-matching-is-and-as-operators) for the best practices)

3. the simple & classic cast using parenthesis as mentioned before.

extra notes:

- You don't need to make separate Enums for each derived type if you use casting properly. Using enums for keeping track of types will only slow you down in long term and gives no advantages relative to casting whatsoever.
- In stackoverflow it's always best if you avoid sending pictures, [here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (usedItem.itemData is Consumable consumable)
{
    thisCharacterStats.DoStatRestoreValue(consumable.restoredType, consumable.restoredValue);
}
```

^ The modified if is doing three things:
The `is` operator is doing a type check to see that itemData is the type `Consumable` and not `null`. The 2nd part of that statement is casting itemData to the Consumable type and storing it in this new `consumable` variable for use in the `if` scope (the variable goes out of scope outside of the if statement). Because the first part is making sure it's not null you don't need to do your own not null check.